# Can a <Ad> tag appear more than once inside the <VAST> tag?

Tags: vast

a. Can a **Ad** tag appear more than once inside the **VAST** tag?

b. Can a **Creatives** tag contain more than one **Creative** element?

Reference: http://ad3.liverail.com/?LR_PUBLISHER_ID=1331&LR_CAMPAIGN_ID=229&LR_SCHEMA=vast2

Answer (score 7):

Within the `<VAST>` element there can be one or more root `<Ad>` elements (at least one is required).

While a single `<Ad>` element represents the most common VAST response, multiple ads may be included as either stand-alone ads or a pod of ads (aka Ad Pod -introduced in VAST 3.0-), or a mix of both. Ads in a pod are distinguished by using the *sequence* attribute for an `<Ad>`, denoting which ad plays first, second, and so on. If the player supports ad pods, sequenced ads are played in numerical order and all ads in the pod should be played to the best of the player's ability. All sequence values in a VAST response must be unique. Non-sequenced ads, are stand-alone ads and considered part of an "ad buffet" from which the player may select one or more ad to play in any order.

The `<Creatives>` container (required -- only one may appear) can hold one or more `<Creative>` elements, in the form of Linear, NonLinear, or CompanionAds.

See [VAST 3.0 spec](http://www.iab.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/VASTv3_0.pdf) for full details.

Comment: The answer isn't correct: **(VAST 2)** *A single VAST response may include **multiple Ads** from multiple advertisers. It will be **up to the Video Player** to determine the **order, timing, placement, etc** for the multiple ads. However, the player should generally respect the
sequential order of the Ad elements within a VAST response. * Meaning: *par. 1 is wrong* as for VAST 2 multiple Ads are supported, *par. 2 is wrong* as multiple doesn't mean Ad-Pods!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I corrected my answer.